# Mongodb: assert that all elements in an array have a field not null

Tags: mongodb, mongoid

Given a collection with documents like this:

Task Collection document

```
[
{
 "_id"=>BSON::ObjectId('54d674b64d42504b6a000000'), 
 "submissions"=>
  [{"_id"=>BSON::ObjectId('54d674b64d42504b6a010000'),    
    "grade"=>nil,    
    "user_id"=>BSON::ObjectId('54d1e2454d42503069060000')},
   {"_id"=>BSON::ObjectId('54d674b64d42504b6a020000'),       
    "grade"=>nil,            
    "user_id"=>BSON::ObjectId('54d1e2454d42503069070000')},
   {"_id"=>BSON::ObjectId('54d674b64d42504b6a030000'),    
    "grade"=>nil,    
    "user_id"=>BSON::ObjectId('54d1e2454d42503069080000')}
   ],
 },
{
 "_id"=>BSON::ObjectId('54d674b64d42504b6a100000'), 
 "submissions"=>
  [{"_id"=>BSON::ObjectId('54d674b64d42504b6a010000'),    
    "grade"=>5,    
    "user_id"=>BSON::ObjectId('54d1e2454d42503069060000')},
   {"_id"=>BSON::ObjectId('54d674b64d42504b6a020000'),       
    "grade"=>7,            
    "user_id"=>BSON::ObjectId('54d1e2454d42503069070000')},
   {"_id"=>BSON::ObjectId('54d674b64d42504b6a030000'),    
    "grade"=>nil,    
    "user_id"=>BSON::ObjectId('54d1e2454d42503069080000')}
   ],
 },
{
 "_id"=>BSON::ObjectId('54d674b64d42509b6a000000'), 
 "submissions"=>
  [{"_id"=>BSON::ObjectId('54d674b64d42504b6a010000'),    
    "grade"=>8,    
    "user_id"=>BSON::ObjectId('54d1e2454d42503069060000')},
   {"_id"=>BSON::ObjectId('54d674b64d42504b6a020000'),       
    "grade"=>7,            
    "user_id"=>BSON::ObjectId('54d1e2454d42503069070000')},
   {"_id"=>BSON::ObjectId('54d674b64d42504b6a030000'),    
    "grade"=>6,    
    "user_id"=>BSON::ObjectId('54d1e2454d42503069080000')}
   ],
 }
]
```

How can I get all the tasks documents whose `submissions` array contains no nil grade?

The result in the example would contain just the last one.

I am using Mongoid, but I welcome a pure Mongodb query too.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using `elem_match` and a negative comparison:

```
Task.where(:submissions.elem_match => { :grade.ne => nil })
```